# В каких случаях употреблять "позвонить", а в каких "звонить"?

Tags: грамматика

Пытаюсь научиться говорить по-русски, если вы мне поможете, то я буду очень рад! 
Всегда путаю и неправильно говорю вот эти слова:

> позвонить звонить
>   отковырять ковырять
>   проставить ставить
>   пускают спускают
>   увидеть видеть
>   сменить менять
>   поговорить говорить
>   прописать писать
>   и т.д.

В каких ситуациях говорятся первые, а в каких вторые? В чём разница?

Первые - это в основном с приставками, вторые - без. В чём разница?

И в чём тогда разница между "заплатить" и "оплатить"?

Заранее вам спасибо, жду ваших ответов.

Comment: Добро пожаловать в Russian SE.  Ваш вопрос очень расплывчат.  Пожалуйста, сформулируйте, что именно, смущает вас при использовании этих слов. Если английский вам ближе, чем русский, то вопросы по английски тоже привествуются в этом стэке.

Comment: Hi, the community behaves strangely again, so here's just a brief outline.

Comment: All in all, you've made verb mistakes at the very beginning: "пытаюсь" must have a soft sign and both "научиться" / "выучить" cannot be used with any ellipsis; they require a compliment, either a verb or a noun: "пытаюсь научиться говорить по-русски" / пытаюсь выучить, как говорить по-русски.

Comment: Then you start with будете + помочь, which is also wrong aspectually. It should be either  будете помогать (future imperfect) or  поможете (future perfect). NB: the future forms with буду / будешь can never be used with perfect forms of verbs. Only imperfect verb forms can be used for Future Imperfect.

Comment: oплатить/заплатить  you can read about that http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/36471/

Comment: This are verbs of different aspect (perfective and imperfective) - similar question is here - [Talking about perfective and imperfective verbs](http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/2537/551).

Answer (score 3):

В списке у нас первый глагол совершенного вида, второй несовершенного.

позвонить – звонить
отковырять – ковырять
проставить – ставить
спускают – пускают 
увидеть – видеть
сменить – менять
поговорить – говорить
прописать – писать

Чем они отличаются?

Глаголы совершенного вида

1.описывают **завершенное действие** или то, которое **будет завершено** в будущем. Они не употребляются для действий, происходящих сейчас.

> Завтра я поговорю с отцом. Ты позвонил другу?

2. относят действие к **определенному времени**, не могут описывать общие события.

> Позвони ему завтра.

3. описывают  результативные действия. Что‐то сделано или будет сделано.

> Я прочитал всю книжку. (Книга прочитана). Я сменю рубашку.

4.Действие обычно кратковременное.

> Посижу (немножко).

Глаголы несовершенного вида

1. описывают незаконченное действие

> Звоню, звоню – все без толку.

2.Описывают, что вы делаете сейчас, обычно делали, обычно делаете, будете делать регулярно.

> Я говорю, что это правильно. И всегда говорил. И буду говорить.

3.Показывают процесс, а не результат.

> Я читаю. Иногда хожу в кино. Я буду кататься на лыжах зимой.

4.Действие более длительное.

> Я занимался весь вечер. Я буду слушать музыку еще часа два.

Answer (score -1):

Первая группа (позвонить, отковырять) – завершенная форма глагола. Обычно так говорят об однократных действиях, которые нужно завершить.
Вторая группа (звонить, ковырять) – это неопределенная форма. Так вы говорите о действиях, которые 1) делаете регулярно (простое время) или 2) в течение длительного времени (продолженное время).

По смыслу оплатить и заплатить – это одно и тоже. Но примеряется по-разному: оплатить что-то, ЗАплатить ЗА что-то.