# сказать VS поговорить

Tags: выбор-слова, вид

What's the difference between these two? According to wiktionary both are perfective forms of *говорит* but I'm not sure if they're really interchangeable. When should each one be used?

Comment: It's **to say** vs **to have a talk**.

Comment: Related.https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2537/talking-about-perfective-and-imperfective-verbs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сказать means to make one or more statements which have the effect of informing the listener on some clearly identified subject. For example:

> Скажите что я позвонил.
>
> Хорошо, скажу.

In contrast поговорить means to have a talk with someone. It conveys the idea of uttering appropriate words in order to revolve a situation or to make one's position clear. For example:

> Наш сын меня не слушает. Ты должен с ним поговорить.
>
> Хорошо, я поговорю.